# Can I copy parts of a glossary verbatim in my thesis?

Tags: writing, plagiarism

My thesis uses domain language of a (software) project that needs to be precisely defined because those words are ambiguous in the "natural" English language. This software project hosts a glossary using [Attribution 4.0 International](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) that I would like to include partly (ca. 20 out of 60 terms).

Can I write the following?

> ## Glossary
>
> The XYZ project glossary¹ defines a set of terms that are used throughout this thesis:
>
> **A** [Verbatim text defining A]
>
> **B** [Verbatim text defining B]
>
> ....
>
> ---
>
> ¹ https://link.to.project.website.glossary

*I saw several questions about copying normal text but I think this does not apply here, because I am not copying scientific findings but merely a definition of a "language"?*

Comment: Statement "The XYZ project glossary¹ defines a set of terms that are used throughout this thesis:" doesn't make it clear that you are copying the definitions, make that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The license makes it pretty clear that this is allowed. However, you should probably also, in the footnote, give the license as well as the link. Then a reader needn't follow the link to know that it is licensed.

You might even make it more clear that you are quoting from the original.